# NPM -bash command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I am trying to run through nodeschool.io exercises.  I am having trouble running their packages.

The first package I installed:

```
$ npm install -g learnyounode
$ learnyounode
```

Runs the package with the command `learnyounode`

Every other package on their site I tried installing and can't run the program with the proper command in the command line, ex:

```
$ npm install -g functional-javascript-workshop@latest
$ /Users/name/npm/bin/functional-javascript -> /Users/name/npm/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/functional-javascript.js
/Users/name/npm/bin/functional-javascript-workshop -> /Users/name/npm/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop/functional-javascript.js
functional-javascript-workshop@0.0.27 /Users/name/npm/lib/node_modules/functional-javascript-workshop
├── lorem-ipsum@0.1.1 (inflection@1.2.7, optimist@0.3.7)
└── workshopper@0.7.2 (map-async@0.1.1, tuple-stream@0.0.2, split@0.2.10, through@2.3.6, mkdirp@0.3.5, colors-tmpl@0.1.0, xtend@2.1.2, terminal-menu@0.2.0, optimist@0.6.1, msee@0.1.1)

$ functional-javascript-workshop
$ -bash: functional-javascript-workshop: command not found
```

Here is a link to the package I am trying to install in the example: [functional-javascript-workshop](https://github.com/timoxley/functional-javascript-workshop)

As you can see, I am getting the message
`-bash - command not found`

Looking at other posts with similar problems, I ran the following commands to see my path and where the packages are being saved:

```
$ which node
$ /usr/local/bin/node

$ which npm
$ /usr/local/bin/npm

$PATH 
$ Users/name/.rbenv/shims:/Users/name/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin: No such file or directory
```

Steps I tried:

- Uninstall/Reinstall node using brew commands
- global update npm's ($ npm update -g)

It looks like my node-modules are being installed at `/Users/name/npm/lib/node_modules` I'm not sure though how to give my command line access or a way of looking into that path for the command to start the program.

Comment: If you try `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/name/npm/bin` does that help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `functional-javascript-workshop` executable is in `/Users/name/npm/bin`, which is not in your PATH variable, add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/name/npm/bin
```

Then you should be able to run `functional-javascript-workshop`

Comment: You can also add this to your bashrc or your bash_profile to get an easier to read version of you paths:

    alias path='echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}'         
Then all you have to do is type

    path
and you will echo all executable Paths.

Other notes:

You can prepend your npm command with "sudo", you don't have permission to write to the global module directory.

Comment: the . in front of the name means it is hidden, you can see hidden files in linux or unix terminal by typing ls -a from the correct directory where the file is present, in this case they will be in your home directory so you can type ls -a ~/