# bash: npm: command not found

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

When I check the version of Node, it says

```
v8.0.0
```

but when I check the version of NPM, it says

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

Previously, my action was

`npm install -g "@angular/cli"`

That's when it consistently shows the `npm: command not found` message.

I tried searching for possible solutions but none worked like the `brew` and others.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125358/npm-bash-command-not-found?rq=1

Comment: This means that npm is not available in global path. export npm(if it was installed properly) directory to path and it should work.

Comment: try with a more recent version of node like 10.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this:

`npm config set prefix /usr/local`

Answer (score 8):

The npm file should be in /usr/local/bin/npm. If it's not there, install node.js again with the package on their website. This worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I have understand your problem, you have installed node and as well as you can install node legacy and npm. follow below commands you will easily solve

> sudo apt-get remove npm,
>   sudo apt-get remove nodejs-legacy,
>   sudo apt-get remove nodejs ,
>   sudo rm /usr/bin/node ,
>   sudo apt-get install nodejs ,
>   sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy ,
>   sudo apt-get install npm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Webstorm terminal in Windows 10 (but it worked in CMD and Powershell) when using NVM.

```
$ npm
bash: npm: command not found
```

I installed a new Node version (I think that will works too even if you are not using NVM) and used it. And NPM was available again

```
$ nvm install 8.11.2
$ npm use 8.11.2
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -4):

I think your laptop have password. so, to install npm you have to run :
sudo npm install
and then enter your laptop password